# How do I raise a vector to a vector in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

So I want to create a matrix of size n x p for vectors of size n x m and m x p.
The first vector should be put to the power of each number in the second vector (consecutive integers in my case).

Example:

```
a = [1 2 3 4];
b = [1; 2; 3];

%some simple operation like this
c = a ^ b;

%giving
c = [1 2 3  4
     1 4 9  16
     1 8 27 64];
```

Both of these work

```
c = repmat(a, 3, 1).^repmat(b, 1, 4);

%or
c = flipud(vander(1:4)');
c = c(2:4,:);
```

But they look clumsy...
Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Try `bsxfun(@power, a, b)`: see http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html